# JQuery get all elements not below

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a problem: I want to get all elements with class dirty not below a dirty element :) As you can guess it's used to refresh contents of viewports. 
My take so far:

```
$(".dirty").not(".dirty .dirty")
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simplest way is by using the jQuery `:not` selector.

In your case:

```
$(".dirty:not(.dirty .dirty)").whatever();
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hart1994/btbG4/1/)

Explaining the `:not` selector:

> The :not(selector) selector matches every element that is NOT the
>   specified element/selector.
>
> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable
>   selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not()
>   selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.
>
> A selector with which to filter by.

Take a look at the CSS3 `:not` selector on [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) and the [jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much, esp. for the link to jsFiddle, I didn't know it and it seems to be a great tool.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, that's pretty much the best approach. You could use the [`:not` selector *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) though:

```
$(".dirty:not(.dirty .dirty)")
```

jQuery can directly pass this selector to the native browser methods if available.

There might be other ways but they are not necessarily "better" (whatever that means in this case).